# "A problem occured when checking for updates"

Tags: python

Ubuntu 23.04

Note that I'm a complete newbie, it's probably something simple but I'm taking lots of time to figure out what to do. So, when I upgraded ubuntu from 22.something, my system started using python 3.11 instead of 3.10, which caused me some problems. So I wanted to be able to use it and used [theses](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-multiple-alternative-versions-of-python-on-ubuntu-20-04-237be5177474) [tutorials](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/10/compile-install-python-3-10-ubuntu/) in an attempt to get both versions.

After struggles result is I can use 3.10 fine but some core system things broke, like a notification saying what's in the post title, and a few things not opening (for exemple the terminal from the desktop, I can open it from inside a file though)

Quick summary of my situation :

python3 --version

```
Python 3.10.6
```

Python --version

```
Python 3.11.4
```

So both are there and it's doing weird things... What can I do from there?
I now know that messing with python installs without doing it virtually is a bad idea but I have an hard time figuring that out too.

I know I'm not very exhaustive in my problem description but I'm not sure what's useful

Comment: I now made an altinstall of 3.11.4 and made python3 and python show the same thing but it didn't change a thing

Comment: Messing about with python destroys your system.